# Convert date string to datetime in SSIS

Tags: datetime, ssis, type-conversion, data-conversion

I am having trouble converting date string to datetime in SSIS. The problem is that the source data store dates in this format: m(m)/d(d)/yyyy, i.e. 3/8/2014, 10/5/2013, 12/22/2014. I have already tried to use data conversion and it won't work. Also I have checked data quality and they are all good - no weird strings. Does anyone know how to fix the package please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you try to convert the dates? What type, format did you use? Is the source type a string or are you converting a datetime to a string while loading it in SSIS?

Comment: "I have already tried to use data conversion and it won't work." What did you try, what was the input data, and what did the failure look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you for the feedback. The source is Excel sheet. Before converting the data, I have a derived column to get rid of irregular data and left this field either empty or the Unicode string of the format above. In the Data Conversion transformation, I put data type as [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]. While running the package, I got error: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your feedback. please see my comment above

Comment: @user2683470: Well it's still not clear what you mean. Showing your *code* would make it easier to understand...

Comment: Agreed. What is the expression you used in the transformation? Can you please edit your answer and paste the expression into here.

Comment: The message doesn't point to a date format error. Perhaps another field is causing the error. Redirect the error outputs and check the faulting lines to see what's wrong as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141679.aspx). You can redirect to a file or to a dummy `Union` task and add a `Data Viewer`. You can have a `Union` task without outputs which makes them great for debugging. We still need the specific settings used when converting though. You can specify much more detail in "Advanced Settings"

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Script Transformation for this. You can then leverage the .NET Framework which has far superior functionality e.g. DateTime.TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert Date to unicode string and now you can convert with derived column element.

Derived Column Code:

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(col,FINDSTRING(col,"/",2) + 1,4) + "-" +
          SUBSTRING(col,1,FINDSTRING(col,"/",1) - 1) + "-" + 
          SUBSTRING(col,FINDSTRING(col,"/",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(col,"/",2) - FINDSTRING(col,"/",1) - 1))
```

Result:

```
col         NewDateColumn
3/8/2014    2014-03-08 00:00:00.0000000
10/5/2013   2013-10-05 00:00:00.0000000
12/22/2014  2014-12-22 00:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used. It formats the col to yyyy-MM-dd format then converts to a DT_DBDATE so if you just want the date string you can remove the wrapping cast.

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(MYCOL,FINDSTRING(MYCOL,"/",2) + 1,4) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + SUBSTRING(MYCOL,1,FINDSTRING(MYCOL,"/",1) - 1),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + SUBSTRING(MYCOL,FINDSTRING(MYCOL,"/",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(MYCOL,"/",2) - FINDSTRING(MYCOL,"/",1) - 1),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the source so it exported the value as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

So, when it went through SSIS, it was able to convert it natively through the Data Conversion Transformation tool

Answer (score -2):

Try converting to a date then a datetime using `(DT_TIMESTAMP)(DT_DBDATE)`.

Comment: If you can provide codes for the OP, that would be very helpful.